# Add timestamp to all image URLs

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I consider myself fairly bright, but anything but the simples regex goes swoosh over my head I'm afraid.

I'm trying to figure out a preg_replace to replace all image links and add a timestamp (the usual fool-the-cache trick).  So what I am looking for is a regex that would take

```
blah blah blah <a href='blah>blah</a> blah <img src="http://blah.com/test.jpg" /> blah blah <a href="blah"><img src='/tester.jpg' /></a> blah blah
```

and make it into

```
blah blah blah <a href='blah>blah</a> blah <img src="http://blah.com/test.jpg?timestamp=123" /> blah blah <a href="blah"><img src='/tester.jpg?timestamp=123' /></a> blah blah.
```

Is it possible to do it in a single preg_replace?  If not, any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/344643). Use an [XML parser](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

Comment: Yes, it's possible with the right regular expression (unless the HTML is badly deformed). However, SO isn't about people writing code for you, so why not give it a go and then post your code if you need help?

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated after having helped people here myself. I'm saying I'm completely blank on this area, so I would have appreciated some pointers.

Comment: The problem is, and again I am frankly shit at regex, that I end up catching the whole text - so with (<img.+src.?["'])(.+?\.jpg)(['"]).+?> the first $1 will contain the whole from first img tag  up until the last img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML parsing is not so simple.
But you can try something like this:

```
$search = "/(\<img[^>]+src=)(['\"])([^'\"]+)['\"]/i";
$result = preg_replace($search, '\1\2\3?timestamp='.$ts.'\2', $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your page through a JQuery function:

```
var timestamp = '?timestamp=123';
$('img').each(function () {
  if ($(this).attr('src')) {
    $(this).attr('src', ($(this).attr('src') + timestamp));
  }
});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/4DSU3/).

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was unclear.  I had to do this serverside in PHP.  The original question title made this clear, but a moderator changed it for one reason or another.  Appreciate your input!